# Xcode 6 does not allow creation of Mac OS X project using Swift

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6

So, a few days ago I download the new Xcode 6. I'm in the process of learning Swift. But here is the problem: It will only let me make a Swift app for iOS and not Mac OS X.

I start up Xcode and click, "Create New Xcode Project."

Next, I select, "Cocoa Application." But when I try to change the language from Objective-C to Swift, it won't let me! It will only show Objective-C!

[image]

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Swift for OS X isn't officially out yet***.

Quoted from **[developer.apple.com/swift/resources](https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/)**:

> Swift for OS X is coming with OS X Yosemite later this fall. If you
>   are using Swift to write Mac apps, you can download Xcode 6.1 GM seed
>   2 for Yosemite, which also includes the iOS 8.1 beta 2 SDK.

↳ [Xcode 6.1 GM seed 2 for Yosemite Download](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?&appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2F%2Fdevcenter%2Fdownload.action%3Fpath%3D%2FDeveloper_Tools%2Fxcode_6.1_gm_seed_2_ofnue4%2Fxcode_6.1_gm_seed_2.dmg)

Comment: Swift is expected to officially launch in the next 48 hours though. As long as your product doesn't ship to the public until after then, there's nothing wrong with it at all.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert, Please provide the source for that information, thanks.

Comment: Here: http://www.apple.com/live/ also note that every single year for years now, Apple has had a major launch event exactly like that one in october to launch a new release of OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode6-Beta6 ... if you can still get your hands on it ... will create a swift based project, even if you're running on Mavericks. I've been using it to create projects, and then opening them in Xcode6. Then in Xcode 6, to create a swift file, I hit cmd-N and go to the iOS section and pick the swift file type. Xcode 6 adds the swift file to the OS X project without any problems.